# color selected rows in a bar plot

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have a bar plot, which could be created with this code:

```
hplot = barh(data(:,1));
```

This plots all bars in the same color.

Now I want to plot the bars wih row numbers 1, 4 and 5 in red and all others in blue.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. There's nothing ready to use directly.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-1T6UHS/